# Using this.setState is changing my event param values

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working with react typescript component, and what I've noticed is that when I'm using `this.setState`, then it is is changing my event param values. The case is that  I'm using a combobox which is calling on an event called `handleChange`.

```js
   <ComboBox                              
     change={this.handleChange}
     value={"test"}
   />
```

Under is the handler:

```js
handleChange = (e) => {
    $.get('/webapi/getItems?ID=' + e.target.value.id, (data) => {
        this.setState({ textEditorValue: data }); 
    });
}
```

It seems like the `onChange` function is being ran two times.
Because first the event param in the function has the correct values, then suddenly it changes to the basic object for events, also it runs two times the `setState` / the function.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please include more code. I would love to see the the component this `handleChange` is tied to

Comment: Updated.  @Galupuf

Comment: @Bladeluster include the entire component please. you've only added the render() function

Comment: @DanPantry it seem like the change event add the item and remove the item from the array for the event

Answer (score 0):

There is something strange in your code, you seems want to fetch something with you api, but you do nothing with the result aka `data`.

Comment: Sorry, the doc tell me that I should get the item by just using e.dataItem, but it is undefined. my event object is totally different stuctured.

I've corrected the code.

Comment: Do you had a link to the doc?

Comment: Here is the doc: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/wrappers/dropdowns/combobox/